# Bootstrap 3 navbar mobile view - ul and links on same line not new lines

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on Bootstrap 3 navbar header, using one of the default examples.
All the content is put on new lines when collapsing into the mobile view.

I want to put `ul` and links on the same line, ideally on groups of lines instead of one line per item. How do I go about this the best way, do bootstrap provide any good tools for doing this? the code example is default bootstrap navbar code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by making the `.nav > li` elements `display: inline-block;`, but only do that when the screen size is at `max-width: 767px` because that is when Bootstrap 3 `navbar` collapses by default.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav>li {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you RBCunhaDesign, this worked like a charm ! You are a lifesaver :)